# swift: mailcomposeviewcontroller does not dimiss

Tags: swift

I would like to send a mail from my app. Here is my code:

```
if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
    let mail = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mail.mailComposeDelegate = self
    mail.setSubject(subject)
    mail.setMessageBody(text, isHTML: false)
    mail.setToRecipients([adress])        
    present(mail, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Now the mail popup is presented with the fields filled in correctly, but when I hit `Cancel->delete` draft(or whatever the English translation is), it doesn't disappear. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the delegate method `mailComposeController(_:didFinishWith:error:)` and dismiss it yourself.

From the docs

> Your implementation of this method should dismiss the mail composition view. Implementation of this method is optional but expected.

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement the delegate method

```
 func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {
    // Check the result or perform other tasks.
    // Dismiss the mail compose view controller.

    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

as mentioned here in [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messageui/mfmailcomposeviewcontrollerdelegate)